# Strange behavior querying an Int field with a String in MySQL

Tags: mysql

Using MySQL 5.5.60.

I'm running into some peculiar behavior when running select queries in Mysql. I have a table `list` whose schema looks like this:

```
+-----------------------+--------------+------+-----+-----------------+----------------+
| Field                 | Type         | Null | Key | Default         | Extra          |
+-----------------------+--------------+------+-----+-----------------+----------------+
| list_id               | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL            | auto_increment |
| vendor_id             | int(11)      | NO   | MUL | NULL            |                |
| referrer_id           | int(11)      | NO   |     | 0               |                |
...
```

If I run this query

```
mysql> select * from list where list_id = "1946"\G
```

Everything works as it should and the list with id `1946` is returned. Here is where it gets weird. If I change my query to look like this:

```
mysql> select * from list where list_id = "1946dhkdf"\G
```

It still returns list `1946`! Clearly MySQL somehow cast off the `dhkdf` part and uses the `1946` portion only. So does it try to cast that value to an Integer that way? Why then does this query return and empty set?

```
mysql> select * from list where list_id = "xq1946dhkdf"\G
```

I can't seem to find any documentation explaining this behavior. Can someone shed some light on it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are seeing MySQL's somewhat complex casting rules at work here.  When trying to compare an integer column against a string literal, either one has to be cast to integer, or the other to string.  In this case, MySQL will try to cast the string literal to an integer, to match the type of the column.  But, in this case, it can't cast the entire string literal to an integer, since it contains characters.  Therefore, the casting rules kick in, which state that if the first N characters of the string be numeric, then use only that leading number.  So, as a result the following query:

```sql
select * from list where list_id = "1946dhkdf";
```

will return the same result set as:

```sql
select * from list where list_id = "1946";
```

Comment: This makes sense. Do you know if there is a way to flip on some "strict" flag to my MySQL not do that?

Comment: *In this case, MySQL will try to cast the string literal to an integer, **to match the type of the column.*** No. Always. See [Type Conversion in Expression Evaluation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/type-conversion.html). The last rule (compare as floating-point values) is applied in this case.

Comment: @codemonkey The bigger problem here is that you seem to be storing numeric data inside a text columns.  Don't do that.  Instead, consider scrubbing your raw data outside of MySQL and then importing it strictly as numeric.

Comment: @Akina Excellent resource. Thank you.